# Intercepting with XMLHttpRequest for a specific address using greasemonkey

Tags: xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a greasemonkey script that will work on either Chrome and Firefox.. a script that will block XMLHttpRequest to a certain hard-coded url..
I am kind of new to this area and would appreciate some help.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This almost impossible to do with Greasemonkey.  It is the wrong tool for the job.  Here's what to use, most effective first:

1. Set your hardware firewall, or router, to block the URL.
2. Set your software firewall to block the URL.
3. Use [Adblock](http://adblockplus.org/en/) to block the URL.
4. Write a convoluted userscript that tries to block requests from one set of pages to a specific URL.  Note that this potentially has to block inline `src` requests as well as AJAX, etc.

Answer (score 1):

it possible now using

> @run-at document-start
>
> http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at

but it need more improvement, check the example

> http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/125936